# javascript ROWs INDEX when change value of a field

Tags: javascript

I m trying to check controls between two values on 2 fields in same row.
my html part of my table is:

```
<tbody>
            {% for payable in payables %}
            <tr class="item">

                <td>
                    <input class="readonly" id="item-{{ payable.id }}" name="client-{{ payable.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ payable.client }}" readonly >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="readonly" id="duedate-{{ payable.id }}" name="duedate-{{ payable.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ payable.duedate }}" readonly >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="readonly" id="number-{{ payable.id }}" name="number-{{ payable.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ payable.number }}" readonly >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="readonly"><input id="montantttestaxes-{{ payable.id }}" name="montantttestaxes-{{ payable.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ payable.montantttestaxes|floatformat:2|intcomma }}" readonly></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="readonly"><input type=number step="0.01" id="soldedu-{{ payable.id }}" name="soldedu-{{ payable.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ payable.soldedu|floatformat:2|intcomma }}" readonly></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type=number  id="payment-{{ payable.id }}" name="payment-{{ payable.id }}"  required="" type="text" value=0.00 step="0.01" onchange="compare(this);">
                </td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

I had a compare function for payment field I want to get back to my javascript function the row index. for now my code return is undefined...I put rowindex in nbrow variable to log...

this is my javascript:

```
    function compare(y){
        console.log(y.value)
        var nbrow = y.parentNode.rowIndex
        console.log(nbrow)
        var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[nbrow].cells;
        var due = x[4].value
        var payment = y.value
        console.log(due)
        console.log(payment)
        if (due< payment){
            alert("your payment is too high!");
            return false;
            }
    }
```

thanks for help

Comment: How are you calling this function? What is '`#myTable` element? Please post a full code, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to change `y.parentNode.rowIndex` to `y.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex`.

**y** is the current element

**parentNode** is the parent of that element, which is `td`

So by using `parentNode.parentNode`, you are getting the parent of the parent, which is `tr`. Which will have `rowIndex` associated.